# How to use Watcher in kubernetes client?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core

I'm using [kubernetes client for C#](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp).

I encountered an issue that after 40-50 min the console application continue working but doesn't register any events. That was because of `Watcher`'s expiring. So I found that I can use `timeoutSeconds` for method I used - [`WatchObjectAsync`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/466e33995d39338987efdd1ad6860dfdda08ae9c/src/KubernetesClient/Kubernetes.Watch.cs#L16). I changed the code - added `int.MaxValue` for `timeoutSeconds`:

```
    var path = $"api/v1/watch/secrets";
    _secretWatcher = await client.WatchObjectAsync<V1Secret>(
        timeoutSeconds: int.MaxValue,
        path: path, 
        onEvent: new Action<WatchEventType, V1Secret>(DoSmthWithEvent));
```

But the problem still remains. But now it happens after 1.5 - 2 hours.

So I want to have console application that is always running and reacting to object changes in kubernetes.

And my question is - how to properly use `WatchObjectAsync` or alternative method? Should I sometimes recreate the `Watcher` object in `_secretWatcher`? And if so, then why does the parameter `timeoutSeconds` exist?

*Additional info:*

- According to [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/issues/266#issuecomment-388494307), watches need to be wrapped in a loop.
- I tried recreating the watcher in `onClosed` callback - works fine. Or better to use while loop?